# How to fix linearization with stackable traits and abstract overrides

Tags: scala, inheritance, types, mixins, self-type

First time in Scala that I have had any real type linearization problems and I can't seem to figure it out.

Assume that I have a test where I want to do this:

```
class Magical(magicNumber: Int)

class MagicianSpec extends Magical(123) with FlatSpecLike with BeforeAndAfterEach {

  var result = false

  override protected def beforeEach(): Unit = {
    result = true
    super.beforeEach()
  }

  "This" should "do what I want" in {
    assert(result)
  }
}
```

Now I want to create an `abstract class` that extends `Magical` but also mixes in `BeforeAndAfterEach` so that in my tests I can just extend the one class and have a bunch of other default behaviour mixed in for free.

Here is what I tried first:

```
abstract class RandomMagic(seed: Int) extends Magical(seed) with BeforeAndAfterEach { thisSuite: Suite =>

  override protected def runTest(testName: String, args: Args): Status = thisSuite.runTest(testName, args)

  var result = false

  override protected def beforeEach(): Unit = {
    result = true
    super.beforeEach()
  }
}

class LuckSpec extends RandomMagic(1) with FlatSpecLike with BeforeAndAfterEach {

  "This other one" should "do what I want" in {
    assert(result)
  }
}
```

This doesn't work. It must have `abstract` and `override` modifiers which means it must be a `trait` which then means it can't have a constructor so no way to extend `Magical`.

This is as far as I get by trying to insert a type with a concrete member into the linearization:

```
abstract class RandomMagicHelper(seed: Int) extends { val rand = new Random(seed) } with Magical(rand.nextInt) { thisSuite: Suite =>

  override protected def runTest(testName: String, args: Args): Status = thisSuite.runTest(testName, args)
}

abstract class RandomMagic(seed: Int) extends RandomMagicHelper(seed) with BeforeAndAfterEach { thisSuite: Suite =>

  override protected def runTest(testName: String, args: Args): Status = thisSuite.runTest(testName, args)

  var result = false

  override protected def beforeEach(): Unit = {
    result = true
    super.beforeEach()
  }
}
```

So now it compiles at least but the test fails.

Can someone explain why it doesn't do what I thought it should? Also is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: I am sorry if I am just too stupid, and don't get something that's supposed to be obvious to any imbecile, but would you be so kind to clarify _what_ "must have `abstract` and `override`" and/or (better yet) show the actual error you are getting? Also, what's the point in defining `beforeEach` if you are also overriding `runTest` - the only place where it is used?

Comment: I certainly wouldn't call you stupid. The common reference seems to be this http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html by Bill Veners who is also the (original?) author of `BeforeAndAfterEach`. This is because `BeforeAndAfterEach` is a stackable trait. It needs to be mixed in after a type that implements `runTest` so that `super.runTest` will work. This is what I tried to do with `RandomMagicHelper` and indeed why it compiles (I don't have the error on hand right now). I don't _want_ to override `runTest` but it seems I have no choice.